# Is there a way to disable 4-finger unity gestures without compiling unity sources?

Tags: unity, 13.04, multi-touch, gestures

To date I could only find solutions that involve recompiling unity sources and avoiding updates, is there a way to disable 4-finger unity gestures without compiling unity sources?

#### UPDATE

I already compiled the sources and blocked updates...